# Why doesn't the "Quit" event in Outlook VBA run a passed class module?

Tags: vba, class, events, outlook

I have a macro that, upon the closing of the Outlook client, a private variable is set to an instance of a class module.

The code runs and no errors are thrown. However, the class module that is passed (correct me if I am using the wrong terminology), does not have its subroutine run.

The goal is to create and save a new note item upon application exit.

From "ThisOutlookSession" (Microsoft Outlook Object):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private ShutdownTrigger As Class2

Private Sub Application_Quit()
    Set ShutdownTrigger = New Class2
End Sub
```

From "Class2" (Class Module):

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub ExitApp()
 
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olNoteItm As Outlook.NoteItem

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set olNoteItm = olApp.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
    
    With olNoteItm
        .Body = "murphy"
    End With
    
    olNoteItm.Save

End Sub
```

The note is not being created. Note, the subroutine "ExitApp" code works when placed within the "ThisOutlookSession" object, however.

Also, as an potentially unrelated question, do I need to create a private variable "Shutdown Trigger", or can I use a Dim statement as I do in most subroutines?

Comment: How does `ExitApp` get invoked?  Does Class2 contain more code than what you are showing?

Comment: Yeah that was my flaw, being a beginner, I mistakenly thought that by creating and setting a class module object in the first sub, it would run all sub routine in the class module. As Eugene answered below, I needed to call the ExitApp sub routine as a method on the class module object in the first sub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance in the code to create a new note item Outlook. Instead, you could get an `Application` instance in the `ThisOutlookSession` module and pass it to the method.

Second, you need to call the ExitApp method on the object created:

```
Option Explicit

Private ShutdownTrigger As Class2

Private Sub Application_Quit()
      
    Set ShutdownTrigger = New Class2
    ShutdownTrigger.ExitApp()
    
End Sub
```

Third, the method may look in the following way:

```
Option Explicit

 Private Sub ExitApp(olApp As Outlook.Application)
    Dim olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olNoteItm As Outlook.NoteItem

    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    Set olNoteItm = olApp.CreateItem(olNoteItem)
    
    With olNoteItm
    
    .Body = "murphy"
    
    End With
    
    olNoteItm.Save

 End Sub
```

Read more about class modules in VBA in the [VBA Class Modules – The Ultimate Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-class-modules/#:%7E:text=In%20languages%20such%20as%20C%23,classes%20in%20the%20other%20languages.) article.

Comment: Thanks Eugene for answering the question and for the additional resource. I actually was just looking at that page before seeing your answer!

I am apparently still learning how class modules work. The sub routines within the class modules need to be called as I would a method on any object from a standard object library.

Could I ask an additional question? When I get the "creationtime" property for an Outlook mail, note, etc object, the returned date is 1/1/4051. Do you know why? "Now" returns what I am after, correct date and time (ie: 5/19/2022 11:07:25 AM).

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend posting separate question as new posts so readers could easily recognize Q&A.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks Eugene for answering my previous question about calling class modules.